# Mirror Image of a 2D array

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, mirror

Here's a program. I wanna create a mirror image. I tried this, but it doesn't show anything. Please tell me how to correct this, and also why this doesn't work.
Thanks in advance!

Example Input:

```
1  2  6
3  4  8
```

Output:

```
6  2  1
8  4  3
```

r=row, c=column

Here's the code:

```
System.out.println("Printing mirror array:");
for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
{
 for(int j=(c-1);j==0;j--)
 {
  System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+"       ");
 }
 System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: What is `matrix`? Can you post a bit more code?

Comment: j==0 replace it with j>=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the inner `for` loop, replace the expression `j==0` by `j>=0`.